# Get all DateTime and Nullable<DateTime> properties in T obj using reflection

Tags: c#

I am trying to get all DateTime and Nullable< DateTime > properties of an object.  I am using the following lamda expression, but it returns 0 results.  What is the correct way of doing this?

```
Type t = obj.GetType();

// Loop through the properties.
PropertyInfo[] props = t.GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.GetType() == typeof(DateTime) || p.GetType() == typeof(Nullable<DateTime>)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p.GetType()` will give you the type of `p` which is always `PropertyInfo`. Instead you should be using `p.PropertyType`. For example:

```
Type t = obj.GetType();

//It's a little nicer to keep the types you're searching on 
//in a list and compare using Contains():
var types = new[] { typeof(DateTime), typeof(Nullable<DateTime>) };

PropertyInfo[] props = t.GetProperties()
    .Where(p => types.Contains(p.PropertyType))
    .ToArray();
```